# Concurrency, react-ing to more than one supply at a time

Tags: raku, rakudo

Please consider the code below. Why is the output of this is "BABABA" and not "AAABAA" / "AABAAAB"? Shouldn't the two supplies run in parallel and the whenever fire immedeatly when there is an event in any of them?

```
my $i = 0; 
my $supply1 = supply { loop { await Promise.in(3); done if $i++> 5; emit("B"); } };
my $supply2 = supply { loop { await Promise.in(1); done if $i++> 5; emit("A"); } };

react 
{ 
    #whenever Supply.merge($supply1, $supply2) -> $x { $x.print }
    whenever $supply1 -> $x { $x.print };
    whenever $supply2 -> $x { $x.print };
}
```

Comment: cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331761/print-sth-every-second-and-also-sleep-10-seconds-very-5-seconds-using-react

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When we subscribe to a `supply` block, the body of that `supply` block is run immediately in order to set up subscriptions. There's no concurrency introduced as part of this; if we want that, we need to ask for it.

The best solution depends on how close the example is to what you're doing. If it's very close - and you want to `emit` values every time interval - then the solution is to use `Supply.interval` instead:

```
my $i = 0; 
my $supply1 = supply { whenever Supply.interval(3, 3) { done if $i++ > 5; emit("B"); } };
my $supply2 = supply { whenever Supply.interval(1, 1) { done if $i++> 5; emit("A"); } };

react { 
    whenever $supply1 -> $x { $x.print };
    whenever $supply2 -> $x { $x.print };
}
```

Which simply sets up a subscription and gets out of the setup, and so gives the output you want, however you do have a data race on the `$i`.

The more general pattern is to just do *anything* that gets the loop happening out of the setup step. For example, we could use an a kept `Promise` to just "thunk" it:

```
my constant READY = Promise.kept;
my $i = 0;
my $supply1 = supply whenever READY {
    loop { await Promise.in(3); done if $i++> 5; emit("B"); }
}
my $supply2 = supply whenever READY {
    loop { await Promise.in(1); done if $i++> 5; emit("A"); }
}

react { 
    whenever $supply1 -> $x { $x.print };
    whenever $supply2 -> $x { $x.print };
}
```

Which helps because the result of a `Promise` will be delivered to the `supply` block via the thread pool scheduler, thus forcing the execution of the content of the `whenever` - containing the loop - into its own scheduled task.

This isn't especially pretty, but if we define a function to do it:

```
sub asynchronize(Supply $s) {
    supply whenever Promise.kept {
        whenever $s { .emit }
    }
}
```

Then the original program only needs the addition of two calls to it:

```
my $i = 0;
my $supply1 = supply { loop { await Promise.in(3); done if $i++> 5; emit("B") } }
my $supply2 = supply { loop { await Promise.in(1); done if $i++> 5; emit("A") } }

react { 
    whenever asynchronize $supply1 -> $x { $x.print }
    whenever asynchronize $supply2 -> $x { $x.print }
}
```

To make it work as desired. Arguably, something like this should be provided as a built-in.

It is possible to use a `Channel` as well, as the other solution proposes, and depending on the problem at hand that may be suitable; the question is a bit too abstracted from a real problem for me to say. This solution stays within the `Supply` paradigm, and is neater in that sense.

Comment: Ty for your answer. The background of this a Perlmonks posting from somebody who wants to make a simple game. I was thinking how I would maybe do it. In my comment, supply1 .isa Monster, supply2 .isa Player, both .isa GameObject. Both emit Movement or Action events which are processed in the react block. That was the idea.

Comment: Ah, then it sounds like you're using `Supply` to model concurrent event-producing "actors", and that sounds like a good fit.

Comment: I don't understand how this supply whenever READY pattern works. Could you elaborate? Also I added some code in another comment. Could you have a look at that too? I thibk there is  race in there.

Comment: @Holli I've edited the answer to try and explain a bit more what it does; does this help?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to jjmerelo here, I managed to get it working. The channel was the right track, but you actually have to consume the channels supply.

```
use v6;

my Channel $c .= new;
my $supply1 = start { loop { await Promise.in(1); $c.send("B"); } };
my $supply2 = start { loop { await Promise.in(0.5); $c.send("A"); } };

react 
{ 
    whenever $c.Supply -> $x { $x.print };
}

$c.close;
```

Additional question: How good does that scale? Can you have several thousand supplies sending to the channel?

Comment: You can do both. The last line in my script consumes the channel by turning it into a list. There is always more than one way to do it. You can read from a channel from as many threads as you want, so that would scale (as soon as you don't turn it into a supply)

Answer (score 3):

[Supplies are asynchronous](http://docs.p6c.org/language/concurrency#Supplies), not concurrent. You will need to use [channels](http://docs.p6c.org/type/Channel) instead of supplies to feed them concurrently.

```
use v6;

my $i = 0;
my Channel $c .= new;
my $supply1 = start { for ^5 { await Promise.in(1); $c.send("B"); } };
my $supply2 = start { for ^5 { await Promise.in(0.5); $c.send("A"); } };

await $supply2;
await $supply1;
$c.close;

.say for $c.list;
```

In this case, the two threads start at the same time, and instead of using `.emit`, then `.send` to the channel. In your example, they are effectively blocked while they wait, since they are both running in the same thread. They only give control to the other supply after the promise is kept, so that they run apparently "in parallel" and as slow as the slower of them.

Comment: Not quite, but you sent me on the right track. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here is my real code. It seems to work, but I think there is a race condition somewhere. Here's some typical (albeit short) output.

```
A monster hatched.
A monster hatched.
A hero was born.
The Monster is at 2,3
The Monster is at 3,2
The Player is at 0,0
The Monster (2) attacks the Player (3)
The Monster rolls 14
The Player rolls 4
The Monster inflicts 4 damage
The Player (3) attacks the Monster (2)
The Player rolls 11
The Monster rolls 8
The Player inflicts 45 damage
The Monster is dead
The Monster is at -3,-3
The Player is at 4,-3
The Monster (1) attacks the Player (3)
The Monster rolls 8
The Player rolls 5
The Monster inflicts 11 damage
The Player has 32 hitpoints left
The Monster is at -4,1
The Player is at -1,4
The Player (3) attacks the Monster (1)
The Player rolls 12
The Monster rolls 11
The Player inflicts 46 damage
The Monster is dead
Stopping
Game over. The Player has won
```

Now the strange thing is, sometimes, in maybe 20% of the runs, the last line of the output is

```
Game over. The GameObject has won
```

as if the object got caught while it already is partially deconstructed? Or something? Anyway here's the code.

```
class GameObject
{
    has Int $.id;
    has Int $.x is rw;
    has Int $.y is rw;
    has $.game;
    has Int $.speed; #the higher the faster
    has Bool $.stopped is rw;

    multi method start( &action )
    {
        start {
            loop {
                &action();
                last if self.stopped;
                await Promise.in( 1 / self.speed );
            }
            $.game.remove-object( self );
        }
    }

    method speed {
        $!speed + 
            # 33% variation from the base speed in either direction
            ( -($!speed / 3).Int .. ($!speed / 3).Int ).pick
            ;
    }
}

role UnnecessaryViolence
{
    has $.damage;
    has $.hitpoints is rw;
    has $.offense;
    has $.defense;

    method attack ( GameObject $target )
    {
        say "The {self.WHAT.perl} ({self.id}) attacks the {$target.WHAT.perl} ({$target.id})";

        my $attacker = roll( $.offense, 1 .. 6 ).sum;
        say "The {self.WHAT.perl} rolls $attacker";

        my $defender = roll( $target.defense, 1 .. 6 ).sum;
        say "The {$target.WHAT.perl} rolls $defender";

        if $attacker > $defender 
        {
            my $damage = ( 1 .. $.damage ).pick;
            say "The {self.WHAT.perl} inflicts {$damage} damage";

            $target.hitpoints -= $damage ;
        }

        if $target.hitpoints < 0
        {
            say "The {$target.WHAT.perl} is dead";
            $target.stopped = True;
        }
        else
        {
            say "The {$target.WHAT.perl} has { $target.hitpoints } hitpoints left";
        }
    }
}

class Player is GameObject does UnnecessaryViolence
{
    has $.name;

    multi method start
    {
        say "A hero was born.";
        self.start({
            # say "The hero is moving";
            # keyboard logic here, in the meantime random movement
            $.game.channel.send( { object => self, x => (-1 .. 1).pick, y => (-1 .. 1).pick } );
        });
    }
}

class Monster is GameObject does UnnecessaryViolence
{
    has $.species;

    multi method start
    {
        say "A monster hatched.";
        self.start({
            # say "The monster {self.id} is moving";
            # AI logic here, in the meantime random movement
            $.game.channel.send( { object => self, x => (-1 .. 1).pick, y => (-1 .. 1).pick } );
        });
    }
}

class Game
{
    my $idc = 0;

    has GameObject @.objects is rw;
    has Channel $.channel = .new;

    method run{
        self.setup;
        self.mainloop;
    }

    method setup
    {
        self.add-object( Monster.new( :id(++$idc), :species("Troll"), :hitpoints(20), :damage(14), :offense(3), :speed(300), :defense(3), :x(3), :y(2), :game(self) ) );
        self.add-object( Monster.new( :id(++$idc), :species("Troll"), :hitpoints(10), :damage(16), :offense(3), :speed(400), :defense(3), :x(3), :y(2), :game(self) ) );
        self.add-object( Player.new( :id(++$idc), :name("Holli"), :hitpoints(50), :damage(60), :offense(3), :speed(200) :defense(2), :x(0), :y(0), :game(self) ) );
    }

    method add-object( GameObject $object )
    {
        @!objects.push( $object );
        $object.start;
    }

    method remove-object( GameObject $object )
    {
        @!objects = @!objects.grep({ !($_ === $object) });
    }

    method mainloop 
    { 
        react {
            whenever $.channel.Supply -> $event
            {
                self.stop-game
                    if self.all-objects-stopped;

                self.process-movement( $event );

                self.stop-objects
                  if self.game-is-over;

            };
            whenever Supply.interval(1) {
                self.render;
            }
        }

    }

    method process-movement( $event )
    {
        #say "The {$event<object>.WHAT.perl} moves.";
        given $event<object>
        {
            my $to-x = .x + $event<x>;
            my $to-y = .y + $event<y>;

            for @!objects -> $object
            {
                # we don't care abour ourselves
                next 
                    if $_ === $object;

                # see if anything is where we want to be
                if ( $to-x == $object.x && $to-y == $object.y )
                {
                    # can't move, blocked by friendly
                    return 
                        if $object.WHAT eqv .WHAT;

                    # we found a monster
                    .attack( $object );
                    last;
                }
            }

            # -5 -1 5 
            # we won the fight or the place is empty
            # so let's move
            .x = $to-x ==  5  ?? -4 !!
                 $to-x == -5  ?? 4  !!
                 $to-x;

            .y = $to-y ==  5  ?? -4 !!
                 $to-y == -5  ?? 4  !!
                 $to-y;

        }
    }

    method render
    {
        for @!objects -> $object {
            "The {$object.WHAT.perl} is at {$object.x},{$object.y}".say;
        }
    }

    method stop-objects
    {
        say "Stopping";
        for @!objects -> $object {
            $object.stopped = True;
        }
    }

    method stop-game {
        "Game over. The {@!objects[0].WHAT.perl} has won".say;
        $.channel.close;
        done;
    }

    method game-is-over {
        return (@!objects.map({.WHAT})).unique.elems == 1;
    }

    method all-objects-stopped {
        (@!objects.grep({!.stopped})).elems == 0;
    }



}

Game.new.run;
```

Comment: The data races I see are nothing to do with your original question. Maybe delete this answer and post it as a new question? Only room in this comment for one race. 1 player left --> game-over --> stop-objects --> object.stopped=True for all objects --> RACE IS ON --> PATH1 --> stop-game. PATH2 --> winning game object --> loop --> last --> remove-object --> no references to winning game object left --> GC may reap at any moment --> sometimes PATH1's stop-game catches winning object in the midst of its GC teardown.

Comment: Being more precise about what I thought was a data race as described above... It looked to me like the code `"Game over. The {@!objects[0].WHAT.perl} has won"` in PATH1 might race against `@!objects = @!objects.grep({ !($_ === $object) });` in PATH2 removing the final winning game object from `@!objects`. But thinking about it again I don't understand why you wouldn't sometimes get `"The Nil has won"` or something like that.