# Is there still a race condition?

Tags: asynchronous, raku

this is the current state of my little unimportant async experiment. Can you spot any races or leaks? Common critique is also welcome.

```
class GameObject
{
    has Int $.id;
    has Int $.x is rw;
    has Int $.y is rw;
    has $.game;
    has Int $.speed; #the higher the faster

    multi method start( &action )
    {
        start {
            loop {
                &action();
                await Promise.in( 1 / self.speed );
            }
            #$.game.remove-object( self );
        }
    }

    method speed {
        $!speed + 
            # 33% variation from the base speed in either direction
            ( -($!speed / 3).Int .. ($!speed / 3).Int ).pick
            ;
    }

    submethod DESTROY { say "DESTROY" }
}

role UnnecessaryViolence
{
    has $.damage;
    has $.hitpoints is rw;
    has $.offense;
    has $.defense;

    method attack ( GameObject $target )
    {
        say "The {self.WHAT.perl} ({self.id}) attacks the {$target.WHAT.perl} ({$target.id})";

        my $attacker = roll( $.offense, 1 .. 6 ).sum;
        say "The {self.WHAT.perl} rolls $attacker";

        my $defender = roll( $target.defense, 1 .. 6 ).sum;
        say "The {$target.WHAT.perl} rolls $defender";

        if $attacker > $defender 
        {
            my $damage = ( 1 .. $!damage ).pick;
            say "The {self.WHAT.perl} inflicts {$damage} damage";

            $target.hitpoints -= $damage ;
        }

        if $target.hitpoints < 0
        {
            say "The {$target.WHAT.perl} is dead";
            return True;
        }
        else
        {
            say "The {$target.WHAT.perl} has { $target.hitpoints } hitpoints left";
            return False;
        }
    }
}

class Player is GameObject does UnnecessaryViolence
{
    has $.name;

    multi method start
    {
        say "A hero was born.";
        self.start({
            # say "The hero is moving";
            # keyboard logic here, in the meantime random movement
            $.game.channel.send( { object => self, x => (-1 .. 1).pick, y => (-1 .. 1).pick } );
        });
    }
}

class Monster is GameObject does UnnecessaryViolence
{
    has $.species;

    multi method start
    {
        say "A monster hatched.";
        self.start({
            # say "The monster {self.id} is moving";
            # AI logic here, in the meantime random movement
            $.game.channel.send( { object => self, x => (-1 .. 1).pick, y => (-1 .. 1).pick } );
        });
    }
}

class Game
{
  my $idc = 0;

    has GameObject @.objects is rw;
    has Channel $.channel = .new;

    method run{
        self.setup;
        self.mainloop;
    }

    method setup
    {
        self.add-object( Monster.new( :id(++$idc), :species("Troll"), :hitpoints(20), :damage(14), :offense(3), :speed(400), :defense(3), :x(4), :y(2), :game(self) ) );
        self.add-object( Monster.new( :id(++$idc), :species("Troll"), :hitpoints(25), :damage(16), :offense(3), :speed(300), :defense(3), :x(3), :y(2), :game(self) ) );
        self.add-object( Player.new( :id(++$idc), :name("Holli"), :hitpoints(50), :damage(60), :offense(4), :speed(200) :defense(2), :x(0), :y(0), :game(self) ) );
    }

    method add-object( GameObject $object )
    {
        @!objects.push( $object );
        $object.start;
    }

    method remove-object( GameObject $object )
    {
        @!objects = @!objects.grep({ !($_ === $object) });
    }

    method mainloop 
    { 
        react {
            whenever $.channel.Supply -> $event
            {
                self.process-movement( $event );

                if self.game-is-over
                {
                    "Game over. The {@!objects[0].WHAT.perl} has won".say;
                    $.channel.close;
                    done;
                };

            };
            whenever Supply.interval(0.01) {
                self.render;
            }
        }

    }

    method process-movement( $event )
    {
        #say "The {$event<object>.WHAT.perl} moves.";
        given $event<object>
        {
            my $to-x = .x + $event<x>;
            my $to-y = .y + $event<y>;

            for @!objects -> $object
            {
                # we don't care abour ourselves
                next 
                    if $_ === $object;

                # see if anything is where we want to be
                if ( $to-x == $object.x && $to-y == $object.y )
                {
                    # can't move, blocked by friendly
                    return 
                        if $object.WHAT eqv .WHAT;

                    # we found a monster, see if we can
                    # kill it and move there
                    return
                        unless .attack( $object );

                    # Something just died
                    self.remove-object( $object );
                    last;
                }
            }

            # we won the fight or the place is empty
            # so let's move
            .x = $to-x ==  5  ?? -4 !!
                 $to-x == -5  ?? 4  !!
                 $to-x;

            .y = $to-y ==  5  ?? -4 !!
                 $to-y == -5  ?? 4  !!
                 $to-y;

        }
    }

    method render
    {
        for @!objects -> $object {
            "The {$object.WHAT.perl} is at {$object.x},{$object.y}".say;
        }
    }

    method game-is-over {
        return (@!objects.map({.WHAT})).unique.elems == 1;
    }
}


Game.new.run;
```

Comment: Hi all readers. I presume @Holli posted this in response to [a comment I wrote on an earlier SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486372/concurrency-react-ing-to-more-than-one-supply-at-a-time#comment101560985_57518312). My plan was to do a proper writeup of the race because I thought that would be helpful. I'll still do that tonight if folk don't kill this question. Hi Holli. I apologize. If I'd known you'd be posting code without evidence of a race I would have directed you to post a question at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Hopefully it'll all work out.

Comment: Actually I read your comment which confirmed my suspicion and so I went to eradicate all races I could find, the result being this code. I'm new to this async stuff so I thought I'd double check here. Not appropriate?

Comment: There are already two votes for closing this. You really need to reformulate this question. In general, "check this and tell me what's wrong" questions are not acceptable. If you find something is wrong, please write it down here. Also golf the clode (eliminating commented sentences) to what we actually need to know. So please find the race conditions yourself and ask for help, instead of asking the readers to find them.