# perl6: html color gradient generator

Tags: html, colors, gradient, raku

This question has been moved to [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/227774/perl6-html-color-gradient-generator) in Code Review. Please, answer the question in Code Review. Thanks!

---

Inspired in this [color gradient generator](http://www.herethere.net/~samson/php/color_gradient/), this is a gradient generator in perl6. I wonder if the code could be simplified or improved. It converts the hex colour to base10, calculates the gradient colours, and then converts the colour to base16.

```
my $initial_color = '#FF0000';
my $final_color   = '#00FF00';
my $gradient      = 10;

my @initial   = ($initial_color ~~ /\#(..)(..)(..)/).list.map: { .Str.parse-base(16) };
my @final     = ($final_color   ~~ /\#(..)(..)(..)/).list.map: { .Str.parse-base(16) };
my @range     = @final Z- @initial; 
my @increment = @range.map: { $_ / $gradient };

my @color;
@color.push: @initial;
for (1..$gradient) -> $i {
  @color.push: @(@color[$i-1]) Z+ @increment;
}

for (0..$gradient) -> $i {
  @color[$i] = '#' ~ ( @(@color[$i]).map: { .base(16,0).fmt('%02s') } ).join;
}

my $fh = open '/tmp/delete.html', :w;
for (0..$gradient) -> $i {
  $fh.print: "<span style='background-color:@color[$i]'>&nbsp;</span>"; 
}
$fh.print: '&nbsp';
$fh.close;

run <elinks -dump -dump-color-mode 3 /tmp/borrem.html>;
```

Comment: Hi @Mimosinnet. This post belongs on [stackexchange's codereview site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl6) rather than here. (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562254/is-there-still-a-race-condition#comment101586803_57562254) Maybe leave this question up here so folk see it but *also* post it in codereview, then edit this question to *start* with a comment asking that folk answer there instead (with a link to the codereview post), and then delete it from here if you get an acceptable answer there. Maybe post comments linking to the codereview post in reddit etc.

Comment: I have an answer mostly prepared and readyf or when you add it to codereview.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/227774/perl6-html-color-gradient-generator

Comment: @raiph: Ups... Sorry for posting here. This is a hobby for me and I very much appreciate and thank your suggestion. Moved to code-review. Thanks!